# nginx-prometheus-exporter container cannot connect to nginx

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a docker-compose and both nginx and nginx-prometheus-exporter are containers. I put the relevant parts here:

```
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.19.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"

  nginx-exporter:
    image: nginx/nginx-prometheus-exporter:0.8.0
    command:
      -nginx.scrape-uri
      -http://127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status
```

I tried  `http://nginx:8080/stub_status`,
`nginx:8080/stub_status` and
`127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status` for `-nginx.scrape-uri` but none of them worked and I got `Could not create Nginx Client: failed to get http://127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status: Get "http://127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused`.

Also the localhost:8080/stub_status is available in my VM using curl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem was the missing `-`.

```
 nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.19.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"

  nginx-exporter:
    image: nginx/nginx-prometheus-exporter:0.8.0
    command:
      - -nginx.scrape-uri
      - http://127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status
```

Comment: On my computer it was only working when I used the name of the container instead of the local host in the scrape uri. In this case it would be `- http://sc-nginx:8080/stub_status`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was running nginx-prometheus-exporter in **docker**. Instead of using http://127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status, find the IP of your host machine (where docker is running) by running below command:

```
ip addr show docker0
```

and pass URL in docker **run** command like this:

```
-nginx.scrape-uri=http://<host_machine_IP>:8080/stub_status
```

**Note:** Change **port** and **server url** "/stub_status" in above command as you have configured in nginx

Comment: How can this be done in an automated way?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have NGINX running outside Docker but **still want to use the *localhost* address**, you can specify the `network_mode: host` option. In my case, I did it through Docker Compose.

```yaml
nginx-exporter:
  image: nginx/nginx-prometheus-exporter:1.1.0
  network_mode: host
  command:
    - -nginx.scrape-uri http://127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status
```

In this case, the individual service container will use Docker daemon's host network and ports.

### References

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode
- https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/